Получить поворот объекта
Есть объект - допустим "пуля" и есть персонаж - допустим "человек" и вот когда пуля сталкивается с человеком, нужно получить поворот человека и направление пули, чтобы знать с какой стороны был удар и от этих данных уже включать соответствующую анимацию?

Если у вас, допустим, гуманоидный персонаж, вы можете в нём создать несколько триггер-коллайдеров, которые будут оповещать о попадании. Но имейте в виду, что вы должны траекторию пули самостоятельно указать теми же рейкастами , иначе пуля всегда будет лететь в одну точку.
